# Quiero ordenar la respuesta JSON desde codigo Python en arreglos de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

Soy nuevo con JavaScript y necesito su apoyo para poder obtener 2 arreglos desde la respuesta que obtengo por JSON desde el controlador de Python con la siguiente forma:

```js
{
  "Artefactos-YMS": {
    "Total": 338356.0,
    "Detalle": {
      "1": {
        "Total": 587827.0
      },
      "2": {
        "Total": 635988.1
      },
      "3": {
        "Total": 697516.5
      },
      "4": {
        "Total": 581277.0
      },
      "5": {
        "Total": 410221.1
      }
    }
  },
  "Artefactos-IQT": {
    "Total": 2550515.34,
    "Detalle": {
      "1": {
        "Total": 587827.0
      },
      "2": {
        "Total": 635988.1
      },
      "3": {
        "Total": 697516.5
      },
      "4": {
        "Total": 581277.0
      },
      "5": {
        "Total": 410221.1
      }
    }
  },
}
```

El cual quisiera como resultado 2 arreglos en JavaScript con la siguiente forma:

```
detalle = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

El cual se obtenía de la sección del "Detalle", como se ve tiene más de un recorrido, pero solo quiero el arreglo del primer recorrido y el segundo arreglo quisiera saber si lo puedo hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
dataset = [
          {
            label: 'Artefactos-YMS', // descripcion
            data: [587827.0, 635988.1, 697516.5, 581277.0, 410221.1], // totales
          },
          {
            label: 'Artefactos-IQT', // descripcion
            data: [587827.0, 635988.1, 697516.5, 581277.0, 410221.1], // totales
          },
         ]
```

Comment: JSON es un formato de intercambio; no es relevante quien lo genera.

Comment: claro, el detalle es que no es el JSON si no que lo necesito convertir de JSON a arreglo de JAVASRCIPT